# Can a muslim women delay marriage and deny propsals

Tags: nikah, women

In Islam a woman has the right to turn down marriage proposals but I am aware one should not delay marriage. How can a woman refuse marriage proposals and also not delay marriage.I want some Islamic advice on this. Also, would delaying marriage apply to sisters who are studying.

Answer (score 1):

Marriage is highly recommended. It becomes somewhat mandatory also to do it if you're giving into sins.

Marriage and studying can easily go hand in hand. I've seem women with 4 kids and PhDs.

To summarize. It's permissible, but not recommended. It's not permissible if puts you closer to sins.

Comment: Oh so I can delay marriage for studying and such but its not recommended. And it becomes mandatory, if your sinning?

Comment: @user44908 That's correct.